# how to create dojo data onclick event for dojo dynamic tree in zend framework for programatic approach

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, treeview

i am new to Zend framework and dojo.i have created dynamic tree structure using dojo in zend framework but i want to make on click of each folder and element of tree structure to naigation to another form by writing a  function .Pleas check my code and help me i have gone through  some  dojo on click event link and could not solve  ..

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Tree Structure </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"    href=/dojo/dijit/themes/ claro/claro.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ dojo/dojo/dojo.js" 
         djConfig="parseOnLoad:true, isDebug:true"  >
       </script> 

   <script type="text/javascript">
   dojo.require("dojo.parser");
   dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
   dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
   dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer")
   dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
   dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore"); 
   dojo.require("dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel");
   dojo.require("dijit.Tree"); 
   dojo.require("dojo.parser"); 
  function myTree( domLocation ) { 
  var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({url:    "http://localhost/CMTaSS_module1.0/public/dojo/cbtree/datastore/Family-1.7.json"}); 

 var treeModel = new dijit.tree.TreeStoreModel({
         store: store,
         query: { name:'John'}
        });

  var tree =  new dijit.Tree( { 
             model: treeModel, 
            id: "mytree",
           openOnClick: true
                   }); 
                    tree.placeAt( domLocation );
                } 
var tree_obj = new dijit.Tree({
    model: treeModel

 },
  "tree_obj");

 dojo.connect(tree_obj, 'onClick', function(item, node, evt){
     console.log("Item", item);
     console.log("Node", node);
     console.log("Event", evt);
     //console.log('node: ' +tree_obj.getLabel(node));
     //console.log('event: ' +tree_obj.getLabel(evt));
     console.log('identifier: ' + tree_obj.getLabel(item))
  });

</script>

</head>
 <body class="claro"><br><br><br>
 <div id="CheckboxTree"> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
     myTree("CheckboxTree"); 
   </script> 
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code sample is not formatted correctly as some of the logic is outside the myTree function. I used jsbeautifier.org to confirm this.

Other notes...
You should wait until dojo is ready. Either use [dojo.addonload](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/addOnLoad.html#dojo-addonload) or, [create a widget](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/recipes/custom_widget/) and reference that widget in the html portion of your code. Widgets are amazing and are what make dojo great, so getting a grasp on how they work will pay dividends.

Also note that if creating a widget programmatically (new dijit.Tree), you should call startup on it. This is not needed when creating it declaratively (inline html).

I hope this helps.